# XPAGE validateexpression problem in a time field

Tags: validation, expression, xpages

i'm trying to prevent the user from inserting a period longer than 2 hours in an application form , this is my code : 
i've wrote my validation code in the field "Heure_fin" which is a time field which is calculate the diffrence between "Heur_fin" and "heur_debut"

```
<xp:inputText value="#{document1.Heure_fin}"
                id="heur_fin"
                style="width:31.0%;font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;height:20px"
                disableClientSideValidation="true">
                <xp:this.converter>
                    <xp:convertDateTime type="time"
                        timeStyle="short">
                    </xp:convertDateTime>
                </xp:this.converter>

                <xp:this.validators>


                    <xp:validateRequired message="required field"></xp:validateRequired>


                    <xp:validateExpression>


<xp:this.expression><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var dStart:NotesDateTime =session.createDateTime(getComponent("date_debut1").getValue());
var hStart:NotesDateTime =session.createDateTime(getComponent("heur_debut1").getValue());
var dateTimeStart:NotesDateTime=session.createDateTime(dStart.getDateOnly()+" "+hStart.getTimeOnly())
var hEnd:NotesDateTime=session.createDateTime(getComponent("heur_fin").getValue());
var dateTimeEnd:NotesDateTime=session.createDateTime(dStart.getDateOnly()+" "+hEnd.getTimeOnly())
var hours = dateTimeEnd.timeDifferenceDouble(dateTimeStart)
if ((hours/3600)<=2)

{
     return true
}else
    return false

}]]></xp:this.expression>
                        </xp:validateExpression>
                    </xp:this.validators>
                    <xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper4"></xp:dateTimeHelper>


                </xp:inputText>
```

but i keep getting the following error message : 
    Expression is invalid.
    Expression did not return a boolean value.

i've put the same code in a computed field and it works fine , 
is there any thing wrong that i'm missing , i appreciate your help . 
Regards,

Answer (score 2):

In a validator you need to use `getSubmittedValue()` instead of `getValue()`. See this blog post I did to give more details about the partial refresh (JSF) lifecycle of XPages, which should help explain why https://www.intec.co.uk/understanding-partial-execution-part-three-jsf-lifecycle/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, i've tried that but no success, sorry, same problem

Comment: i've tried to change the get value to "getComponent("heur_fin").getSubmittedValue()" and tried also "this.getSubmittedValue()" but no success , please forgive my shallow experience in xpages.